# SAS proc ttest modify HO

Tags: sas

I have a data with GENDER=(1/0) INCOME SENIORITY=(1/0). I need to run a ttest on INCOME by GENDER for SENIORITY=1. 
As far as I know, the default of HO=0, which means that there is no difference between the genders, but how can I define an HO that will check if mu of female(gender=1) is =higher= than mu of male(gender=0).

this is my basic code:

```
proc ttest data=l;
var INCOME;
class gender;
where SENIORITY=1; 
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This becomes a one sided test, so you use the one tailed p-value. Please see the free SAS training course via SAS University Home Page that has the first statistical course, https://communities.sas.com/community/sas-analytics-u, see the training widget on the left handd side of the page.

If you have a SAS Communities ID and are logged in this link would take you directly to the page.
http://support.sas.com/ecst1

The sides option only affect the CI, the one tailed p-value is the same.  The directionality is dependent on how you set up your hypothesis.

> SIDES=L
>       specifies lower one-sided tests, in which the alternative hypothesis indicates a mean less than the null value, and lower
>   one-sided confidence intervals between minus infinity and the upper
>   confidence limit.
>
> SIDES=U
>       specifies upper one-sided tests, in which the alternative hypothesis indicates a mean greater than the null value, and upper
>   one-sided confidence intervals between the lower confidence limit and
>   infinity.

Comment: I can't access this link. how do I know if its sides=l or sides=u?

Comment: The SAS documentation's first example gives you a great example of exactly this question.